# "&" and Pass by reference

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a function in a binary search tree which returns the address of a particular node:

```
binary_tree_node*& left( ) { return left_field; }
```

I note that the "&" means pass the address of the left_field.
If I deleted the "&", does it mean that it would introduce a compiler error when I am using the function below?

```
root->left()=new binary_tree_node<ItemType>(9);
```

Comment: I'm wondering where in your code you are assigning `root->left()`? If it is not inside of a class method, you might want to reconsider your design to have better encapsulation. If it is inside a class method, why not just assign to `left_field`?

Comment: The code of line 1 I wrote is in a header file. The assignment is in another implementation file and left_field is a private variable.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that `left_field` was private, but what I'm saying is that assigning `left` (via the function or the member) outside of a class method is probably exposing too much implementation details, and assigning inside of a class method, you can just use the private member. Also, letting anyone use `left` to modify the pointer... not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I note that the "&" means pass the address of the left_field

In this case "&" means "reference" not "adress of"

So you are returning a reference on a pointer, not the address of the pointer.

This line would not compile without the "&" :

```
root->left()=new binary_tree_node<ItemType>(9);
```

because you would be assigning a value to a temporary pointer(the return of the left() function). While if you use a reference the pointer returned is the one within your class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there will be a compiler error because the return object is rvalue. But if I am not mistaken MS VC++ (at least MS VC++ 2010) will compile it because thsi compiler has a bug.